# should we explicitly join a thread to finish

Tags: c, pthreads

should we explicitly join a thread to finish? I mean is this like process world: when we don't wait for them to finish we got zombie processes.

Comment: Are you wondering if you can terminate a process (and have the OS clean up all resources) without explicitly joining the threads that might exist in the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily; you can always detach a thread if you don't wan't to explicitly wait for it.

There are a few things to consider:

- If you don't join a non-detached thread it will become a zombie thread (yes, there are such things)
- If you don't join a thread, your main thread might end before the "child" ends
- Once you detach a thread there is no way to attach it back

How do you detach a thread ? There are two ways:

```
detachstate = 1;
rc = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, detachstate);
if (rc) {
    handle error;
}

pthread_create(&thr, &attr, th_fun, NULL);
```

And the second way

```
void *th_fun(void *arg)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
}
```

Comment: when we don't unallocate the memory used in the thread will be it be unallocated by OS when it exits? How about non-detached threads?

Comment: @Majid Azimi I'm sorry, can you explain what you mean ?

Comment: @Majid Azimi When you don't need the memory anymore you have to `free` it. The pthreads API doesn't do this automatically.

Comment: However, the OS will reclaim any memory used by the process when the process exits - whether the allocation was done in the main thread or some other thread. So there's no more need to `free()` memory in a threaded program than in a non-threaded program.

Comment: @MichaelBurr When a detached thread finished, will its memory (allocated with `malloc`) be (instantly) claimed by the OS or only when the main thread finishes?

Comment: @RedX The memory allocated via malloc will be freed when you `free` it or when the process itself terminates.